# From a mixed dtype column, extract string from specific column values in python pandas

Tags: python, pandas

My dataframe looks like below:

```
data = {'pred_id':[np.nan, np.nan, 'Pred ID', 258,265,595,658],
        'class':[np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,'pork','sausage','chicken','pork'],
        'image':['Weight',115.37,'pred','app_images/03112020/Prediction/222_prediction_resized.jpg','app_images/03112020/Prediction/333_prediction_resized.jpg','volume',np.nan]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df
```

Edited:
I am trying create a new column 'image_name' with values from column 'image'. I want to extract a substring from column 'image' values that contains 'app_images/' in its string, and if not then keep it the same.
I tried the below code and its throwing 'Attribute Error' message.

Help me on how to find the dtype and then extract substring from values that have 'app_images/' and if not then keep the value as it is. I dont know how to fix this. Thanks in advance.

```
images = []

for i in df['image']:
    if i.dtypes == object:
        if i.__contains__('app_images/'):
            new = i.split('_')[1]
            name = new.split('/')[3]+'.jpg'
            images.append(name)
        else:
            images.append(i)
        
df['image_name'] = images
df
```

Answer (score 0):

Do not use a loop, use vectorial code, [`str.extract`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html) and a regex.

From your description and code, this seems to be what you expect:

```
df['image_name'] = (df['image'].str.extract(r'app_images/.*/(\d+)_[^/]+\.jpg',
                                            expand=False)+'.jpg'
                    )
```

output:

```
   pred_id    class                                                      image image_name
0      NaN      NaN                                                     Weight        NaN
1      NaN      NaN                                                     115.37        NaN
2  Pred ID      NaN                                                       pred        NaN
3      258     pork  app_images/03112020/Prediction/222_prediction_resized.jpg    222.jpg
4      265  sausage  app_images/03112020/Prediction/333_prediction_resized.jpg    333.jpg
5      595  chicken                                                     volume        NaN
6      658     pork                                                        NaN        NaN
```

[regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/GJ0oTy/1)

Comment: thanks the extract of substring is correct as expected. But the values of other rows in the column are changed to NaN. That is the reason i made a loop but it fails. Could that be fixed?

Comment: there are NaNs as there is no match, what would you like to have? (ideally, edit you question to provide the full expected output)

Comment: @sinG20 so you want to add `.fillna(df['image'])`?